# Why does not .NET add parameter value to exception message, e.g. in int.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Very often in .NET methods throw generic errors like e.g.

```
int.Parse("test")
```

throws an exception with this message:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Now it would save a lot of trouble for many people if it just had the parameter value to help debug things easier:

> Input string "test" was not in a correct format.

This seems like a natural and easy thing to have, yet .NET does not do it in many places like e.g. parsing. Is there is any reason or conceptual problem with doing that or is it just a "missing feature"?

Comment: Probably for security. Input string can contain sensetive information and it's not good if it will be preserved for unknown amount of time in your logs.

Comment: @Evk is probably right. Also consider what you would expect to occur if the string was **very long** (e.g. 20MB long). Would you expect throwing an exception to take > 20MB of memory? _Also, at a conceptual level - what are you achieving by including that value there? The caller knows that value already **because it passed it in**. Nothing stops you generating the exception you want in your own wrapper function that calls `int.Parse`._

Comment: Security seems a legitimate point here so that you must log it explicitly yourself if you want, though I guess you are doing something wrong if you are parsing a 20MB string as a number :)

Comment: Yep. Think about what would happen to yellow screen of death on user input like `<script>alert('you all are going to die down here!')</script>`

Comment: @trailmax Well, should be html encoded by yellow screen of death to show exactly that instead of interpreting it as a script :)

Comment: HTML encoding makes sense if you're running in a context that serves HTML. But C# can be used in other contexts, so making a general solution isn't trivial.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I don't know the inner workings of yellow screen of death. I'm just suggesting hypthetical vulnerability that can be exploited in scenario you suggest.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, I know, just replied to exactly yellow screen of death comment, but I agree that the security concern in general is a very valid one

Comment: About 20 MB String: imagine you call WebAPI method that return number as a string. In one day this service falls down,and method returns very long stack trace of exception. This is when you easily could achieve such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the reason is primarily for security reasons. Some concerns with displaying/rendering the text to be parsed in the message returned are (but not limited to)

- The text to be parsed may be very long. This is would be problematic from a memory usage and display perspective not to mention developer's habits of logging exception messages (not unreasonably).
- The text may contain characters that mess with the formatting (e.g., tab, LF, CR, etc.)
- The text may contain sensitive data. On this point, it's worth nothing that most developers, at least starting out, generally log or display error messages at an exception level by default. *Not* including the text here means there's no unintended data leak to catch the unwary.
- It's conceivable (though unlikely) that an exploit could be found whereby a malformed piece of text could have a nasty unintended side effect.

Additionally, the value being parsed is being supplied by the caller which leaves them the option of deciding if it's best to log the content or not - it's not `int.Parse()`'s place to return the value in the exception message.

All in all, displaying a concise message without the originally supplied value is a judicious decision on part of MS to save us from ourselves as well as follow security best practices.